# how to send multiple parameters two web service via soap message?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am able to send one parameter and its working..but same way I used two parameters but its not working. Please view the code bellow,,,,,

```
NSString *soapMessage = 

    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     "<soap:Body>"
     "<hospitalDetails xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
     "<stateName>%@</stateName>"
     "<hospitalName>%@</hospitalName>"
     "</hospitalDetails>"
     "</soap:Body>"
     "</soap:Envelope>",state,hospital];
```

Comment: like this I have used but not worked. But is another case single parameter works gr8.....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Check on webservice side does it accepts more than 1 parameter ?